# Slick slider - double tap bug on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, slick.js

I have a problem with slick slider. It makes me double-click the buttons to make them work properly. For example "zobacz całą ofertę" button or "go up" button. It works badly only on iOs. On Android, Windows, iMac works perfectly. Can someone tell me what it's wrong? On subpages without slick slider everything is ok.

```
(function ($) {
  $('.carousel').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    autoplay: true,
    appendArrows: $('#arrows'),
    nextArrow: '<span class="slick-next slick-arrow"></span>',
    prevArrow: '<span class="slick-prev slick-arrow"></span>',
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I can see the button "Zobacz całą ofertę" is not related to slickslider in any way. Do you suspect slickslider is someway interfering with other page elements?

Comment: Yes I think it's problem with slider because on subpages (without slider) everything works good. I know there is no relation to slickslider and this is strange to me ;p

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. My findings after two days of analysing:

- double click (which means tab, in this case) is just needed after the slickslider registers a touch event with the custom swipeHandler
- Seems like Browsers on iOS do not recognize these events and have problems to react correctly to the first touch outside the slider
- What helped in my case is simply `$(document).on('touchstart', function(event) {});` somewhere in the code
- If someone can explain why, please respond. But I hope that I can help with this workaround.

edit: I think I found an explanation for this behaviour [here](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2014/02/mouse_event_bub.html)